# jsf-2.0: Big pb using forEach beside get parameter

Tags: jsf-2

Here the code, hope you can help me.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{edit.id}" required="true" requiredMessage="required" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{edit.create}" />
</f:metadata>
.....
<c:forEach items="#{edit.elements}" var="element">
    <ui:include src="/include/#{element}.xhtml" />
</c:forEach>
```

I **absolutely** need to include dynamic page because huge number of it unknown in advance... So the problem is 
that method create is called after getting the list of elements due to c:forEach lifecycle.

I also tried preValidate, postValidate and preRenderComponent event but nothing helps.

Thanks a lot; you are my heroes

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to make it work.
Just add the followings:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="#{edit.id}" />

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
private Integer id;
```

It seems to work in any case but not sure about the best practice..